# How to defer the file picker window to appear when using .addEventListener('change' ...) option event?

Tags: javascript, html

When 'click' event option works fine: .addEventListener('click', listenerHandler); then event.stopPropagation(); and event.preventDefault(); does its job. As expected the file picker doesn't appear, it has been holded.

But when I switch to the 'change' event option things goes wrong... the file picker window immediately appears.

.addEventListener('change', listenerHandler);

Unlike the 'click' event, when using 'change' event as soon as I click the button the file picker is shown!

In order to test some conditions before the file picker is shown, is there any way to hold the file picker window from appear when using the 'change' event option?
I need to hold the file picker using the 'change' event option not the 'click' option.

I will appreciate your advice to resolve this issue. Thanks!

```js
var teacher = student = "";
let fileSelector = document.getElementById('dataUpload');

// When the event option is 'change' the file picker is shown,
// when the event option is 'click' the file picker gets hold!

fileSelector.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  listenerHandler(event);
});

// when using 'change' option the event.stopPropagation and
// event.preventDefault looks like does not do its job!

function listenerHandler(event) {
  if (teacher == "" || student == "") {
    fileSelector.removeEventListener('change', listenerHandler);
    // remove.EventListener does not do its job when using the 'change' event option.
    window.alert("Select a Teacher or Student.");
    return;
  }
  // If conditions are okay invoke the next function...

  handleDataUpload(event);
  /* another function to handle the file upload, always
  works okay whether 'click' or 'change' event options running. */
}

function handleDataUpload(event) {
  window.alert("Okay!");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My First Upload!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h3>My First Upload!</h3>
  <input type="file" id="dataUpload" accept=".pdf, .PDF, .jpg, .gif" />

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `var teacher = student = "";` is not the correct way to declare multiple variables. This only declares `teacher`, `student` is created implicitly as a global variable. Use `var teacher = "", student = "";`

Comment: The *change* event is fired when the value of the `<input>` **has been changed** (by the user). For the value to be changed already, the file picker must already have been shown to the user. You apparently already know how to prevent that from happening.

Comment: There's no default action for the `change` event, so `preventDefault()` isn't very useful there.